# snmp exporter info + sysname

Tags: snmp, exporter

i'm scraping the Cisco device with SNMP Exporter. Everything is OK, but i want to somehow add the OID: Sysname into the SNMP information, how to do it ?

Tried to add lookup like:
    - source_indexes: [ifIndex]
      lookup: sysName

but got an error. Maybe you have any clue ?

---

modules:
  # Default IF-MIB interfaces table with ifIndex.
  if_mib_dc:
    version: 3
    auth:
      username: xxx
      password: uuutt
      auth_protocol: MD5
      priv_protocol: AES
      security_level: 33dds2
      priv_password: slypt
    walk: [ifHCInOctets, ifHCOutOctets, ifOperStatus, ifInErrors, ifOutErrors, ifInDiscards, ifOutDiscards]
    lookups:
    - source_indexes: [ifIndex]
      lookup: ifAlias
    - source_indexes: [ifIndex]
      lookup: ifDescr
    - source_indexes: [ifIndex]
      # Use OID to avoid conflict with Netscaler NS-ROOT-MIB.
      lookup: 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1  # ifName
    overrides:
      ifType:
        type: EnumAsInfo

I want to get sysname information like im getting ifAlias lookup.